# Adm Zip - files zipped as folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, adm-zip

I am using `adm-zip` to zip the `local directory and all its nested files and directories.`

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
var pathToZip = process.env.PUBLIC + '/Demo/Backup.zip';
var zip = new AdmZip();
zip.addLocalFolder("C:\\Users\\Public\\Test\\db");
zip.writeZip(pathToZip);
```

**Problem:**

All the files are getting added as folders inside the zip and the actual content is not getting zipped.

Where i am wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug with the addLocalFolder function in Windows, but there is an easy fix, look at this entry:
https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/pull/132/files

Tip: Always check the current state of the library you are working with first. :)

Comment: The issue as you mentioned, i am using an older version of adm-zip. Getting latest version resolved the issue. Thanks @MunchyYDL

Comment: Oh, even better, nice to know that it solved the issue. :)